# How to set width of a View equal to any displaysize?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I am using a `HorizontalScrollView` to slide `TextViews` over the screen . My question now is, if there is any way to make the width of each `RelativeLayout` match the width of the phone screen, independent of the phone the user uses.

So is there a way to like get the display width of the device and then set it as the width of my `RelativeLayout`? Or is there even a better way to do it?

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/info"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="80dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/getrunkeneLiter"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/danke"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Feedback verfassen"
                android:onClick="feedback"
                android:layout_below="@+id/danke"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the screen size and set it to each of your views programmatically. Alternatively, you can use a weighted `LinearLayout` and set its size to number of elements times screen size.

You can use this function to get the screen size (and then use the x value of the `Point`):

```
public static Point getScreenSize(Context context) {
    final Point size = new Point();
    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size;
}
```

To update the relative layouts you need to add an id to each of them. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/first_subview"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">
```

And then in your activity:

```
private void updateViews() {
    Point screenSize = getScreenSize(this);
    updateView(findViewById(R.id.first_subview), screenSize);
    updateView(findViewById(R.id.second_subview), screenSize);
    ...
}

private void updateView(View view, Point screenSize) {
   view.getLayoutParams().width = screenSize.x
}
```

Comment: hey, thank you! How do I set the relativeLayoutWidth to the x value of Point though? .-.

Comment: I updated the example to include the setting part as well.

Comment: This is just genius! Really appreciate your help, thank you!